# How can i delete the superfluous letters

Tags: python

How can i delete the superfluous letters from my answer

```
word = "textexample"

for i in word:
    duplicate = word.count(i)
    if duplicate > 1:
        print(i , duplicate)
```

In this example i only want to see there "t2 e3 x2" and nothing more.

This is my current answer:
t 2,
e 3,
x 2,
t 2,
e 3,
x 2,
e 3,

Comment: Try `collections.Counter('textexample')`

Answer (score 0):

1 simple way to achieve this is to iterate the alphabet instead:

```
for i in alphabet: # alphabet here could be ['a', 'b', 'c', ...
    duplicate = word.count(i)
    if duplicate > 1:
        print(i , duplicate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you read the python documentation about this
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

```
str.count(sub[, start[, end]])
Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in the range [start, end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.
```

[Hint] - because your code did NOT specify the range, so it just counts all over again....